# How to decrypt values in Ektron

Tags: asp.net, email, ektron

I am trying to send an email using gmail smtp server. As the from address and password is needed for authentication, I have to set the same in web.config. And I wish the same to be in an encrypted format.

Ofcourse I am able to encrypt the values using' C:\Program Files (x86)\Ektron\CMS400v(x)\Utilities\ EncryptEmailPassword.exe' and so that I can set the values as encrypted form in Web.config file.

But how can I decrypt the values to its original form in code behind for the smtp server to authenticate.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to encrypt login and password stored in Web.config, best way to use it implemented in asp.net mechanism for that rather then Ektron.

Here you have an example how to do it on connectionstring but you can use any section to encrypt just change connectionstring parameter to something else.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Short of de-compiling the Ektron code to obtain the keys, the encrypted text cannot be decrypted.

The Ektron encryption and app settings are for using the Ektron API to send emails. You don't need to decrypt because the Ektron library will do it for you.

As @Cezary states, one option is to not use Ektron email API and use ASP.Net.